# Finding the derivative of a function with two absolute values within it, using a piecewise function

Tags: derivatives, absolute-value, piecewise-continuity

I'm trying to solve some a problem relating to absolute values. I found online the strategy for solving similar functions from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIHtq67nh7w&list=PLGbL7EvScmU7DfRNwONW7JDDcmB98Gjcs&index=22&t=305s&ab_channel=ProfRobBob

Using the strategy shown:

$y = |2x-3|+1$
solve for $0$, to find where break point in the line will be:
$0 = 2x-3 -> x = 3/2$

By substituting values around the break point, for example:

When: $x=0 $

$y = |2(0) -3| + 1 $
$y = |-3| + 1 $
$y = 4$

(absolute value needs to be taken when x < 3/2)

When: $x=3 $

$y = |2(3) -3| +1 $
$y = |3| + 1 $
$y = 4$

(The result is the same regardless of taking the absolute value when x> 3/2)

We can then represent the first equation to make it piecewise:

$y =   2x - 3 + 1 ; x >= 3/2$
$y =  -2x + 3 + 1 ; x < 3/2$

derivatives would be:

$y  = 2; x >=3/2  $
$y  =-2; x < 3/2$

HOWEVER,
I am trying to solve a function like this:

$y = |x^2 - 3| + |x + 1|$

And Im not sure how to go about it. I tried doing the same as before:

$0 = x^2 -1 + x + 4   ->  -3 = x^2 +x$

But this doesn't seem like the right approach, any advice on what to do?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: hint: $x^2+3>0$ so there is only one absolute value in this expression.

Comment: Thanks have added in the notation now for math. 
"hint: x2+3>0
 so there is only one absolute value in this expression." Okay thanks, but I'm still not sure on the process for solving this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $3$ points of interest $\pm\sqrt{3}$ and $-1$.

So let just examine what does $f$ looks like in the intervals considered.

$\begin{array}{lll}
(-\infty,-\sqrt{3}] & f(x)=(x^2-3)-(x+1)=x^2-x-4 & f'(x)=2x-1\\
[-\sqrt{3},-1] & f(x)=-(x^2-3)-(x+1)=-x^2-x+2 & f'(x)=-2x-1\\
[-1,\sqrt{3}] & f(x)=-(x^2-3)+(x+1)=-x^2+x+4 & f'(x)=-2x+1\\
[\sqrt{3},+\infty) & f(x)=(x^2-3)+(x+1)=x^2+x-2 & f'(x)=2x+1\\
\end{array}$

I'll let you calculate all $6$ values $f'(\pm\sqrt{3})$ and $f'(-1)$.

($3$ points of interest times $2$ intervals per point = $6$ values)

You can also set $f(x)=a(x^2-3)+b(x+1)=ax^2+bx+(b-3a)$

So that $f'(x)=2ax+b$ with $a,b=\pm 1$ the respective signs of expressions inside the absolute values.

Comment: Visualize here https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mrxqqi2k7m

Comment: Great thanks that really helped!